# Как получить значение параметра из ссылки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить значение переменной `page` из атрибута `href`?

```
href="?page=5&pageId=6&hash=a74ca72f5ecbe42aa9dd5fb6ecc49f22dd5ad18e"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var href="?page=5&pageId=6&hash=a74ca72f5ecbe42aa9dd5fb6ecc49f22dd5ad18e";
var partsQ = href.split("?");
var partsAmp = partsQ[1].split("&");
var page = null;
partsAmp.forEach(el => {
  var parts = el.split("=");
  if (parts[0] == "page")
    page = parts[1];
});
console.log(page);
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение в функционалом стиле:

```js
const href = '?page=5&pageId=6&hash=a74ca72f5ecbe42aa9dd5fb6ecc49f22dd5ad18';
const { page } = href
  .split('?')
  .pop()
  .split('&')
  .map((ptr) => ptr.split('='))
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), {});
console.log(page);
```